# Вопрос по командам Linux

Tags: linux

Введите правильную последовательность команд, разделяя их `&&` и не пользуясь командой `cd`:

1. Скопируйте в домашнюю директорию файл `/etc/debconf.conf`.
2. Найдите его по названию в домашней директории и удалите его, используя `find` и `exec`.

1 `cp /etc/debconf.conf ~/home/user/`

2 `find -name "*.conf" -exec rm {} \` - система не принимает

Comment: читать `man find`

Comment: На и первая команда странная

Comment: первая команда cp /etc/debconf.conf ~/home/user/ (можно cp /etc/debconf.conf ~/) копирует файл в домашнюю директорию (проверено в VM VirtualBox Ubuntu).

Comment: вторая команда  find -name "*.conf" -exec rm {} \  работает в VM VirtualBox Ubuntu, 
но учебная платформа не принимает ее

Comment: Вторая команда удалить все conf-файлы, а не только требуемый

Comment: спасибо, нашел ошибку: не указал домашнюю директорию.
правильное решение find ~/ -name "debconf.conf" -exec rm {} \;

Comment: `find ~/ -name "debconf.conf" -delete`

Answer (score 3):

Нашел ошибку: не указал домашнюю директорию. Правильное решение:

```sh
find ~/ -name "debconf.conf" -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: `cp /etc/debconf.conf ~/home/user/` - тут масло маcляное. Или `~` или `/home/user/` так как это одно и тоже

Comment: совершенно верно (спешил): 
домашняя директория : ~/ или /home/user/